# UIView hitTest blocks click in child views

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uiscrollview, hittest

I have the following structure of the views

```
UIView(1)
   |--> UIScrollView
        |-----------> UIView(2)
                        |------> UIButton
```

hitTest in *UIView(1)* has been overridden with the following:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint) point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    /* this view should have only view only: the scroll view */
    UIView * vv = [[self subviews] objectAtIndex:0];

    if ([vv pointInside:point withEvent:event])
    {
        UIView *rv = [vv hitTest:point withEvent:event];
        return rv;
    }

    if ([self pointInside:point withEvent:event])
    {
        return vv;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

This is required in order to catch *UIScrollView* dragging outside of the scroll view itself.

The issue is that when the UIButton is clicked, the event attached to it does not fire. The view returned from the *hitTest* is *UIView(2)*.

How can I make the *UIButton* to respond to clicking event?

**Edit**
After suggestion of *Mundi*, I exchanged hitTest with the following and it works. Of course, I forgot to call [super hitTest:].

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint) point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    /* this view should have only view only: the scroll view */
    UIView * scrv = [self findScrollView];

    UIView *superView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    if (superView == self)
    {
        return scrv;
    }

    return superView;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about calling `[super hitTest:point withEvent:event]` at the appropriate point?